# Alter namespaces on elements

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I have an xml document and an existing xslt transform (both of these are relatively large pre-existing code).

In various places through the XML, I have nillable fields declared like this:

```
<author i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

However, I also already have this namespace declared in the xml element like so:

```
<message xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I have had a request that the output for any nil node should look like the following:

```
<author xsi:nil="true" />
```

i.e. the i:nil should become xsi:nil and the namespace declared on the element be removed.

Ideally I would like to amend the existing transform to apply this to any node within the XML that would require this, however I am having some difficulty in phrasing a search to get any results as to how this would be done.  If anybody could help, that would be appreciated.

(I am unable to use any xslt 2.0 cleverness, just in case that affects the answer).

Slightly larger sample input:

```
<message xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <paper>
    <name>A name</name>
    <author i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </paper>
  <paper>
    <name>Another name</name>
    <author>
      Peter
    </author>
    <details>
      <publishDate i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <location>London</location>
    </details>
  </paper>
</message>
```

And desired output:

```
<message xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <paper>
    <name>A name</name>
    <author xsi:nil="true" />
  </paper>
  <paper>
    <name>Another name</name>
    <author>
      Peter
    </author>
    <details>
      <publishDate xsi:nil="true" />
      <location>London</location>
    </details>
  </paper>
</message>
```

Comment: Please post a larger example of you XML input, so that we can understand the context. Is `message` the root element?

Comment: Sorry - message is the root element.  This is a slightly altered output from the original message which I won't be able to post unfortunately.  I will see if I can put something simple together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an identity transform and two separate templates to handle

- attributes that are prefixed with `i`
- elements that have an attribute which is prefixed with `i`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute::i:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{concat('xsi:',local-name())}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[attribute::i:*]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.mynamespace.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

Nillability attributes are now prefixed with `xsi:` and the Schema instance namespace is declared on the root element only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <paper>
      <name>A name</name>
      <author xsi:nil="true"/>
   </paper>
   <paper>
      <name>Another name</name>
      <author>
      Peter
    </author>
      <details>
         <publishDate xsi:nil="true"/>
         <location>London</location>
      </details>
   </paper>
</message>
```

Comment: +1 for the last template. Although I believe it would have passed without it as well (i.e. with the now redundant namespace declaration left intact).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks - I am not sure I understand, though. If I omit the last template, then e.g. the `author` element keeps the `i` namespace.

Comment: If you omit the last template, then the `author` element keeps the `i` namespace **declaration**. The element itself is not (and never was) in the declared namespace; it continues to belong to its ancestor `message`'s namespace.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's what I meant to say, sorry for being imprecise. Still, removing redundant namespace declarations (`xsi`) is a plus, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks very much. Agree with Mathias, last template match is very clever.

Comment: Well, I started with a plus... But IMHO it's worth clarifying that the change is purely cosmetic. OTOH, changing the prefix while retaining the namespace is also purely cosmetic, so go figure.